# Allowing user to change private piece of information on ASP.NET MVC 3 form

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

On an ASP.NET MVC 3 form we have a field that contains private account number that we never display to user, and we do not store it in our system (we pass it to back-end system one-way). We only know if it was previously provided or not. User sometimes may choose to modify the value, so we display it as follows:

```
@Html.PasswordFor(x => x.Private, new { id = "txtPrivate" })
```

Then if we receive the field as empty, we know user did not change anything. It works fine, but is slightly confusing to user, as he sees the field as empty on UI. Ideally we would like to show few dots to indicate to user something has been entered before, and can be changed. What would be the best way of doing that?

I think simple workaround would be to send five-letter "magic" value to UI, and then compare the model on the post, but that is obviously not a nice solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange requirement requires strange solution, what if you'll use `placeholder` for this:

```
@Html.PasswordFor(x => x.Private, new { id = "txtPrivate", placeholder="*******" })
```

it's value will not be submitted to the server as far as I know.

Everybody except bloody IE supports it, but there are workarounds for this.

Comment: Thanks - that is an interesting solution. Unfortunately, that would not work for me for couple of reasons - the empty value may be allowed, and if user clears the textbox placeholder appears. Also styling for placeholder in Chrome is different that normal text, which makes it fairly obvious it is just a placeholder. I start to think there is no easy solution to this problem.

Comment: After all, we ended up, going with this solution after all - well done.